# Is there a way to verify that no threads block?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, async-await

If I have a method:

```
    public async Task<string> Get()
    {
        Task<string> a = _db.GetSomething();
        Task<string> b = _db.GetSomethingElse();

        await Task.WhenAll(a, b);

        return a.Result + b.Result;
    }
```

I don't fully control the code in `_db`, and would like a way to programatically verify that they are using non-blocking io inside. Yes, they have converted to a `Task` based api, but that could easily be accomplished with `Task.Factory.StartNew`and still use blocking IO underneath. That would be undesired in this case.

I do have access to the code, so I can see that they are indeed using Task Factory inside, so decompiling is not really what I am looking for. Ideally I could write a unit test to verify the threading behaviour moving forward.

Is there a way I can somehow check the worker thread count at various points and verify that threads are or are not being blocked in any of these child tasks?

Comment: Unit testing someone else's code?  Why!?

Comment: Really it is a set of internal libraries that are intercepting my code and doing weird things. I'm trying to have a programatic way to show that they are altering the bahavior in bad ways.

Comment: Really it is a test that my code has consistent threading behavior. If libraries I depend on change their behavior, I want to know about it.

Comment: Normally this is detected with timeouts

Comment: I've suggested a duplicate which seems to address your question. TL;DR: apply load and break the debugger. Look at the stacks.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use Microsoft Fakes (Ultimate only IIRC) or JustMock to capture calls to `Task.Factory.StartNew`. Personally, I don't think the effort is worth it.

If you don't care about doing it in code, you can (somewhat) easily see it using the Concurrency Visualizer (or PerfView).